# REGex - how come ([ÆØÅæøåa-zA-Z0-9.-]+)$ works but ([a-zA-Z0-9.-ÆØÅæøå]+)$ doesn't?

Tags: regex

This is a part of my URL

```
-pony-byggesættet-har-ikke-bare-vundet-vores-hænder-men-ogsa-vores-hjerter-
```

I was surprised by the result. I had to include a few special symbols, and found out that

```
([a-zA-Z0-9.-ÆØÅæøå]+)$
```

doesn't catch the URL whereas

```
([ÆØÅæøåa-zA-Z0-9.-]+)$
```

catches the URL. Could anyone kindly explain why is that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What regex environment? Php?

Comment: `.-Æ` is a range.

Comment: @Paulb 
The environment is PHP

Comment: @ctwheels

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That is because:

```
.-Æ
```

looks for:

> a single character in the range between . (index 46) and Æ (index 198)

and your second regex adds all desired characters including `-` into the list.

Same bavior happens with:

```
a-z
```

That looks for:

> a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index
>   122) (case sensitive)

You can find out more on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bM4CCd/1).

Comment: To expand on this... in your second expression the hyphen is being treated as a character to match because there is no range terminator following it whereas in the first expression it is treated as a range separator rather than a literal character.

Comment: Thank you guys for the replies. I appreciate your effort.